# Angular how to map key and value

Tags: angular

So I'm trying to map and object. It has a key and that key has a value.
I get the whole receipt from the server and this is the part with payments (It's the preview of the response I got):

```
paragonSequenceNumber: null
payments: {CARD: 4, CASH: 8}
pkp: "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
```

So I'm mapping it and then using it in html with *ngFor and then writing out the values for the keys.
this is my ReceiptDTO:

```
export interface ReceiptDTO {
        payments: {[key: string]: number }; // key: ReceiptPaymentType (enums)
}
```

This is my ReceiptViewModel

```
interface ReceiptViewModel {
  payments: {[key: string]: number }[]; // I'm not actually sure what to put here
}
```

This is the PaymentViewModel

```
interface PaymentViewModel {
  CASH: number;
  CARD: number;
  VOUCHER: number;
}
```

And this is what I tried using for the ReceiptViewModel
,first Just using it like this:

```
payments: data.receipt.payments,
```

Then like this:

```
payments: Object.entries(data.receipt.payments).map(([key, value]) => {
        return <PaymentViewModel>{
          CASH: value.CASH,
          CARD: value.CARD,
          VOUCHER: value.VOUCHER,
        };
      })
```

But none of the work and what I'd like to happen is to be able to use it in html like this:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let payment of receipt.payments">
        <tr>
          <th>{{'models.Receipt.payments.paymentType.CASH' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{payment.CASH}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>{{'models.Receipt.payments.paymentType.CARD' | translate}}</th>
          <th>{{payment.CARD}}</th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: does the reciept contain the array of payment info about different products?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you are asking, but the Receipt contains thing like id and other info and also payments. Payments is an object which has values like I mentioned at the top of the question. So yeah 
receipt = { 
id= number,
payments = SomeViewModel[],
date = Date,
 }. Also the payment info isn't for a product but for the whole receipt. It's info about the way the customer paid for the items that were bought

Comment: I mean will there be only one object of payment or multiple object of payment in receipt, I am asking since you mentioned that you are recieving payment data from server, but you did not mention whether you are getting different payment info for same receipt from server or only one payment info for a receipt.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'll edit it. I am getting the whole receipt from the server and the receipt has as I mentioned in the previous comment an object with arrays of different payment types. So lets say someone paid 5$ with Card and 10$ cash the object inside the receipt will be of 2 arrays one CARD : 5 and the other CASH: 10.

Comment: I have added the answer, let me know if this is producing the desired behavior or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to display the different types of payment done for a recipt in * ngFor, so my below answer is based on that assumption

You said you are getting this response

```
paragonSequenceNumber: null
payments: {CARD: 4, CASH: 8}
pkp: "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
```

and your ReceiptDTO is mapped like this

```
export interface ReceiptDTO {
        payments: {[key: string]: number }; // key: ReceiptPaymentType (enums)
}
```

everything seems fine till now
here I think for ReceiptViewModel you need to update like this

here make a interface for PaymentTypeInfo like this

```
interface PaymentTypeInfo {
    paymentTypeName: string;
    paymentTypeValue: number;
}
```

then specify the type

```
This is my ReceiptViewModel

interface ReceiptViewModel {
  payments: PaymentTypeInfo[]; // basically array donates the different type of payment like cash, card, etc. then for each index i.e type of payment, which contain the paymentTypeName and it's value
}
```

This is the PaymentViewModel as you mentioned

```
interface PaymentViewModel {
  CASH?: number;
  CARD?: number;
  VOUCHER?: number;
}
```

based on the value of payment that we assigned  I thing we need to update this one like this

```
payments: Object.entries(data.receipt.payments).map((key, value) => {
    const currentPaymentTypeInfo : PaymentTypeInfo = {
        paymentTypeName : key,
        paymentTypeValue: value
    }
    return currentPaymentTypeInfo;
};
```

once it is done, we need to update the html part like this

```
<tbody *ngFor="let payment of receipt.payments" >
    <tr>
        <th>Payment-Type : {{payment.paymentTypeName}}</th>
        <th>It's value : {{payment.paymentTypeValue}}</th>
</tbody >
```

Comment: It works thanks. But now I get this message in  payments: Object.entries(data.receipt.payments), -------------------------

TS2322: Type '[string, number][]' is not assignable to type '[][]'.   Type '[string, number]' is not assignable to type '[]'.     Types of property 'length' are incompatible.       Type '2' is not assignable to type '0'.-------------------------- It works with any[] though, should I Leave it like that or is that not good?

Comment: Also isn't there a better wait then payment[0] and payment[1]. Something like payment.value and payment.key?

Comment: I think that is typscript complaining about unspecified types for payment : [][], if you are confident about what type will always be there for payment types, you can define those or any is also fine, in this scenario, any will be much better as array can't have two types, I am also updating the answer for type safety.

Comment: Well I'm certain I will definitely get either of these 3: VOUCHER, CARD, CASH. It cannot be anything else nor nothing. Also since the PaymentViewModel isn't used it does not need to be there

Comment: @C0mpl3x yes, you can make an interface for example 'PaymentTypeInfo' having properties - PaymentType and PaymentTypeValue, and then you make payments  array like this 'payments : PaymentTypeInfo []'

Comment: @C0mpl3x even though you are sure about that, I went for future proof direction, i.e if  in future if payment type changes for example CARD become CARDS, you won't have to worry about changing this part of the code

Comment: @C0mpl3x updated the code by replacing payment[0] and payment[1] by the property key and value. let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly and as intended. Again thanks for your help I appreciate it. It works as intended although is used  return <PaymentTypeInfo>{ instead of  const currentPaymentTypeInfo : PaymentTypeInfo = {

Comment: @C0mpl3x, both ways can be used, it's just matter of preference, you can use <PaymentTypeInfo> at the right hand side of assignment or while returning the object which is typecasting the object to force it to behave like PaymentTypeInfo (so now typescript will keep the checks of properties for us), and I used the type check for the variable that is keeping the reference of the object, so again typescript will make sure that variable can only contain reference of specified type and keep properties of assigned object in it's check